# Mexican citizen with a 2 yr old US citizen son can he travel by plane within Mexico?

Tags: air-travel, passports, paperwork

My son was born in the U.S. now we live in Mexico. I am a Mexican citizen but my son is not, not yet.
Can he travel by plane here in Mexico with me and it is only within Mexico that we will be traveling.

Comment: Have you asked the air carrier what identification they'll require?

Answer (score 3):

[AeroMexico](https://aeromexico.com/en-us/travel-information/passengers) says the following for accompanied children between the age of 2 and 16:

> Children traveling with parents, guardians or third parties If a
> Mexican or a foreign national child, who is a permanent, temporary, or
> a temporary resident student in Mexican territory, flies accompanied
> by their parents, guardians, or third parties, the minor must produce
> one of the documents below:
>
> On domestic flights:

> Birth certificate
>
> Current passport
>
> Current school photo ID card
>
> Unique Population Registration Number (CURP)

International flights are more complicated.